# BytesOf() and wchar_t arrays

Tags: c++builder

I found that there is an api called `System.UnicodeString.BytesOf` to get byte arrays of the `UnicodeString`.

However, I do not know the benefit of using the function.

Instead, we can use `wchar_t` arrays like:

```
wchar_t szBuf[100];
wcscpy(szBuf, str.c_str());
```

What is the usefulness of the `BytesOf` function comparing to those using `wchar_t` array?

Comment: The correct name is `System.SysUtils.BytesOf()`, which has an overloaded version that takes a `UnicodeString` as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BytesOf()` converts a string to a byte array.  In the case of the overloaded version that takes a `UnicodeString` as input, it converts the `UnicodeString` data to the OS's default Ansi charset before then copying the resulting data to the array (IOW, `BytesOf(UnicodeString)` is just a wrapper for `TEncoding::Default->GetBytes(UnicodeString)`).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Remy Lebeau. So, the UnicodeString is converted to the default Ansi charset, not to the wide charset?

Comment: That is correct. There are separate `WideBytesOf()` and `PlatformBytesOf()` functions that convert a `UnicodeString` to an array of UTF-16 encoded bytes (they both use `TEncoding::Unicode->GetBytes()` internally) instead of Ansi.